# How to configure Keycloak for my Single Page Application with my own Login form?

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I have a **SPA** (Vue) that communicates via **REST with a Quarkus Backend**. I would like to use **Keycloak for Authentication/Authorization**. However, I do not need the whole "Browser Flow" Keycloak feature, instead my SPA has its own Login Form to get a JWT from Keycloak (Direct Grant Flow). This token will be used to communicate with my REST Endpoints.

```
Frontend -> gets a JWT from Keycloak 
Frontend -> gets access to protected resources with that JWT.
```

However I came accross [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) that vehemently discourages devs from using the Direct Grant flow. So what now? Is there a way to still use my own login form with Keycloak?

Something along the lines of:

```
Frontend login -> Backend -> Keycloak Authentication/Authorization -> JTW
Frontend -> gets access to protected resources with that JWT.
```

I am slightly overwhelmed by all the different configuration possibilities in Keycloak and Quarkus. So far I managed to get a token from keycloak with a **public client (direct grant)**, and that token is being used to access protected resources. My Quarkus backend knows the keycloak server too and communicates with it **via a second client (acces type: confidential)**

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/myrealm
quarkus.oidc.client-id=backend-service
#quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=my-secret
```

However, I am not sure why this works at all since the secret is commented out. Why would I need it in the first place ?

Comment: The idea behind open-id / oauth is that users get used to login only on this one keycloak website which is one central secure point. If you start longing in via your own form/logic you kind of go against the whole idea. Not saying it is not possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to use the authorization code flow with a custom theme for keycloak : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/

As you are using react, you can take a look at https://github.com/InseeFrLab/keycloakify which allows you to reuse your react component with keycloak theming.

(Disclaimer: I belong to the organization maintening this library)

Comment: I am using Vue, not react ^^

Comment: :) I read REST as react, my first sentence still stands.

Comment: I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried your solution. The auth flow works, however I am having the same problem with my second client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123537/why-is-quarkus-oidc-credentials-secret-being-ignored