# Why is quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret being ignored?

Tags: keycloak, quarkus-oidc

I have a **SPA** (Vue.js) that communicates via **REST with a Quarkus Resource API** .
I am using my own **Keycloak for Authentication/Authorization**.

In Keycloak I have two clients in my realm:

```
Client ID: frontend-client
Access Type: public
Standard Flow enabled
```

```
Client ID: backend-client
Access Type: bearer-only
Secret: mySecret
```

My application.properties for my Quarkus API:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://localhost:8082/auth/realms/myrealm
#quarkus.oidc.client-id=backend-service
#quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=mySecret
```

My SPA uses the Standard Flow to authenticate with Keycloak and then redirects to my app ✅

Then I can make requests to my API and everything works **despite quarkus.oidc.client-id and quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret being commented out** ! Why is that? It also works when those lines are not commented out but with **false values.**

Why is Quarkus ignoring those lines, and, more importantly, why does it work?

**UPDATE**
Adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Allows me to add this to application.properties:

```
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

It now leads to this error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bearer-only not allowed"}
```

But at least now the secret is not being ignored, and providing a wrong secret leads to the correct error.

**Follow-up question: Why is bearer-only not allowed?**

Comment: Do you have the quarkus-oidc dependency in your pom.xml ?

Comment: Yup, quarkus-oidc. I even had quarkus-keycloak-authorization before, but I removed it since I was not sure I needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that because your Quarkus application use a bearer only client, it will only check the authenticity of the bearer token using the signature.

Since it will not make any call to Keycloak for additional verifications, it will not use the client id and client secret in your properties.

You need to change the type of the client to confidential if you want quarkus to use that.

By the way, in the quarkus quickstart for protecting service applications : the keycloak client use a confidential client, and bearer only is set to false : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/security-openid-connect-quickstart/config/quarkus-realm.json#L395

Comment: I updated my question - but I will try your solution now.

Comment: I think my answer is still valid since to use keycloak authorization you need a confidential client with an enabled service account :)

Comment: We are getting there :) Now I get "Client application [backend-client] is not registered as a resource server." Where do I do that?

Comment: Do you really want to use keycloak authorization ? You will need to use the keycloak admin ui (or api) to define who can do what on your resource server. If you only want to protect your api routes via annotation (eg: @RoleAllowerd("ADMIN")) you don't need keycloak autz. That being said, to turn your client  into a resource server and enable fine-grained authorization, select Access type confidential and click the Authorization Enabled switch to ON then click Save. You can then configure the authorizations in the authorization tab of your clent.

Comment: I don't want to use it if I don't have to - I simply find it rather difficult to understand what does what in Quarkus. So you are suggesting I remove keycloak authorization? By doing so, I lose the ability to use quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable, which in turn seems to ignore the quarkus.oidc.client-id and quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret properties. And we are back to square 1 ^^

Comment: The bearer token is itself secure (your quarkus app check its authencity using the signature + the public key of your keycloak server), you don't really need to use client id / client secret in this case. But If you want to force your app to refresh the user info you can add quarkus.oidc.user-info-required=true in your properties.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the point of the secret and Client Authenticator then? Do I even need it?

Comment: In the end, do I really need the two clients in Keycloak? It seems to work just fine with only the public frontend-client 